# Check if an element is present in 2d array using binary search

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, data-structures, binary-search

Write an efficient algorithm that searches for a value in an m x n matrix. This matrix has the following properties:

Integers in each row are sorted from left to right.
The first integer of each row is greater than the last integer of the previous row
[click for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfkwm.png)

Comment: Hey! Stack Overflow is all about problems. Your question describes a task and you expect us to do it for you.
It doesn't describe a *problem* that you are having when you try to *solve* the task *yourself*. At this state your question isn't [on-topic for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Please rewrite it so it becomes on-topic. Feel free to apply the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) recommendations. Doing so will maximize your chances of getting a high-quality answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean searchMatrix(int[][] matrix, int target) {
    if(matrix.length == 0 || matrix[0].length == 0)
        return false;
    int row = binarySearchRow(matrix,0,matrix.length-1,target);
    return binarySearch(matrix,0,matrix[0].length-1,target,row);
   }

private static int binarySearchRow(int arr[][], int l, int r, int x) { 

        if (r >= l) { 
            int mid = l + (r - l) / 2; 

         //check if element is in between first and last element of that row
            if (x >= arr[mid][0] && x <= arr[mid][arr[0].length-1]) 
                return mid; 

         //if not move on to check other halves
            if (arr[mid][0] > x && arr[mid][arr[0].length-1]>x) 
                return binarySearchRow(arr, l, mid - 1, x); 

                 return binarySearchRow(arr, mid + 1, r, x); 
        } 

    return 0;
}
  public boolean binarySearch(...,row){..apply normal bs here..}
```

Comment: this was accepted with 0ms in leetcode